# How to extract a specfic sub-section from a long JSON using JSON_EXTRACT/REGEXP_EXTRACT on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, regex, google-bigquery

I have a long JSON column that has various nested JSON fields. I am interested in a specific field called **regularHours**, and wish to extract all the values associated with this nested key (the values are arrays of structs).

How can I extract these values using JSON extract? I have tried two approaches - using JSON_EXTRACT and REGEXP_EXTRACT, and I am having trouble extracting the whole field.

Below is the part of the JSON that I wish to extract:

```
"regularHours":[

        {"daysBitArray":[true,false,false,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,true,false,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,true,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,true,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,true,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,false,true,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},
        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,false,false,true],"endTime":"21:30","startTime":"10:30"}
               ]
```

The actual JSON is quite huge, so unable to post it here. But it's general structure is like below:

```
data        
   menuMapping      [2]
   menuStructures       {1}
   menus        {1}
           d62628f4-9b10-4099-aed0-69f904a3a91e     {6}
                 createdAt  :   2020-11-10T19:53:00.244Z
                 displayOptions     {3}
                      currencyCode  :   USD
                      disableItemInstructions   :   false
                      isMenuV2  :   true
                 entities   :   null
                 sections       [1]
                    0       {12}
                        createdAt   :   2020-11-11T07:10:54.511Z
                        externalNotes   :   
                        image   :   null
                        invisible   :   false
                        regularHours        [7]
```

(regularHours is the field I am interested in extracting.)

1. If I use REGEXP_EXTRACT, what should be the Regex code I should use to extract the regularHours array?
2. If I were to use JSON_EXTRACT, how can I give the JSON path to regularHours without actually specifying the parent paths? For example, the path for the above is - **"$.data.menus.d62628f4-9b10-4099-aed0-69f904a3a91e.sections.0.regularHours"**
   However, the value "d62628f4-9b10-4099-aed0-69f904a3a91e" is a dynamic indentifier, and changes with each record. Is it possible to use JSON_EXTRACT without specifying this key value explicitly?

Comment: Is there more than one key under menus?

Comment: No, there is only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately BigQuery's JSON handling is not well set up to do this type of thing. You can work around it by defining a custom javascript function to extract the values:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_regular_hours(input JSON) RETURNS ARRAY<JSON> LANGUAGE js AS """
  const menuKey = Object.keys(input.data.menus)[0];
  return input.data.menus[menuKey].sections[0].regularHours;
""";
```

Then you can use that in a query:

```sql
WITH test AS (SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(
  [STRUCT<j JSON>
    (JSON '{ "data": { "menuMapping" : [1,2], "menus" : { "d62628f4-9b10-4099-aed0-69f904a3a91e" : { "createdAt" : "2020-11-10T19:53:00.244Z", "sections" : [ { "invisible" : false, "regularHours":[        {"daysBitArray":[true,false,false,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,true,false,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,true,false,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,true,false,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,true,false,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,false,true,false],"endTime":"01:00","startTime":"10:30"},        {"daysBitArray":[false,false,false,false,false,false,true],"endTime":"21:30","startTime":"10:30"}               ]}]}}}}')])
)
SELECT get_regular_hours(j)
FROM test
```

I've only used a sample of your data structure but it does represent the same path as you have in your question.

If you may have JSON in the table that doesn't match the input format, you will need to use optional chaining in the function to deal with that:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_regular_hours(input JSON) RETURNS ARRAY<JSON> LANGUAGE js AS """
  const menuKey = Object.keys(input?.data?.menus || {})[0];
  return input?.data?.menus?.[menuKey]?.sections?.[0]?.regularHours || [];
""";
```

Comment: I am unable to get the desired output using this. This is the piece of code I ran:

```CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_regular_hours(input JSON) RETURNS ARRAY<JSON> LANGUAGE js AS """
  if (get_regular_hours === null || get_regular_hours === undefined) {
    return [];
  const menuKey = Object.keys(input.data.menus)[0];
  return input.data.menus[menuKey].sections[0].regularHours;
""";

SELECT get_regular_hours(response)
FROM table```

However, it is giving me an error:

"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at get_regular_hours(JSON) line 7, columns 2-2"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @VivekSingh it looks like you're having issues with data in the table which doesn't match the format. Please see my edit for a version of the function which will deal with that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. 

I had another ask, if you do not mind: If I wish to learn more about UDFs, and building Javascript UDFs, are there any good resources?

Again, huge thanks!

Comment: @VivekSingh good to hear that it worked. TBH there isn't a lot of docs, I learnt from the [google pages](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/user-defined-functions) and just knowing JS. I don't claim to be an expert, just know enough to be dangerous. :)